# Javascript DOM -- onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I got a link in my html code with an `onclick` event handler.

The handler insert a link somewhere in my code with himself an `onclick` event handler.

here is a fiddle representing this:

http://jsfiddle.net/qENap/

My problem is that the onclick handler on the DOM generated link is automatically called.

What did I did wrong?

Comment: So, what is your question? An example at http://jsfiddle.net would be most useful.

Comment: I don't understand the question at all... it sounds a bit like you are executing your handler and assigning the return value to `.onclick` but I'm really not sure.

Comment: Question edit with all the comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eLink.onclick` should have a **closure** assigned to it, not a string.

If you want to go with the string version, use `eLink.setAttribute("onclick","......");`, however this is not recommended.

Alternatively, just do this:

```
eLink.onclick = function() {window.open(dir+"/"+file,"Images","width=1200,height=800");};
```

However, might I ask why you can't just set the appropriate `href` and add `target="Images"`?

Comment: Because I wan't to popup the picture so it's the only way I know...

Comment: Btw It's work with your Answer Thks a lot